# WooCommerce - Change Subtotal on Cart and Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the total in the cart and checkout, multiplying it by 10. (because it currently shows me the 10% deposit price - Woocommerce Deposite plugin -, but I would like to display the total price without deposit).

So I thought about multiplying that by 10.

[image]

I've created a copy of the cart-totals.php in my child theme. And I would like to modify this string of code to display the price multiplied by 10.

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

So something like: `<?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?> * 10`  ----> 6100

Or if it's simpler, I'd like to add up the prices of the products on the left: 1500+4600 ---> 6100

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//calculator price
function calculator_price( $price, $values ) {

    $new_price = $price *= 10;
    return $new_price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 'calculator_price', 10, 2 );

// display new price
function my_new_price( $values, $item ) {
 return wc_price( $item[ 'line_total' ] );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'my_new_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I added this code in my functions.php file, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Marco Bagiacchi, I just tested this code, it works...

Comment: I put the code in the functions.php and the 'Total' stays the same, the only thing that changes is the 'Discount' which is multiplied by 10